# tfs see change set version of the current working folder

Tags: tfs

In the source control explorer it says per file if we have the latest or not, and if you right click and view properties it says the latest version and the workspace version. Is there any way to see the overall latest version and the current workspace version (and possibly to add columns for the two on a per file basis rather than having to check each file's properties one by one)?

We are using both VS2012 and VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

Not from the GUI but you can use the `tf properties` command to get that with `/recursive` option

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzy14b58.aspx